# Getting last date in range of 2 dates

Tags: python, date, iteration

Im am trying to get all dates in a range to make a list of dates:

When I start at 09/Jan/2017 xxx and end at 11/jan/2017 i expect the following dates:

- 2017-01-09
- 2017-01-10
- 2017-01-11

the problem is i only get

- 2017-01-09
- 2017-01-10

what have i missed here to get the 3rd date

```
def generate_index_date_list():
# format like  "11/Jan/2017:11:11:11 +0200"
start_datetime_string = "09/Jan/2017:11:11:11 +0200"
end_datetime_string = "11/Jan/2017:11:11:11 +0200"

startdate = datetime.strptime(start_datetime_string.split(":")[0], "%d/%b/%Y").date()
enddate = datetime.strptime(end_datetime_string.split(":")[0], "%d/%b/%Y").date()
for single_date in daterange(startdate, enddate):
    print single_date


def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

Comment: Don't forget that `range` goes up to but doesn't include the end value. Just think about it in terms of numbers. If `daterange` was `4-2` then it would only yield 2 dates, where as if it was `5-2` it would yield 3. You have to add 1 to your `daterange` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days) + 1):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

Python `range` generates numbers up to, but not including the number given. That is why the last date doesn't get included.

Comment: Really xD, l already thought it must be the most derpiest thing ever. Thanks